# Detect diff to specific yaml file field between two branches with Git and Bash

Tags: bash, git, gitlab-ci

I have a yaml file that has a field `data.version` which I want to detect changes from main branch.\

The yaml looks something like this:

```yaml
# ...
data:
  version: 1.2.3
# ...
```

There are more fields which are not relevant for this purpose.

I am writing a GitLab-CI script where I have my current commit checked out.
I am able to see the changes in general by using this command:\

```bash
git fetch origin main
git diff origin/main HEAD -- my_yaml_file
```

But this does not allow me to detect changes to this specific field...

Is there a way to get and parse the original file from main branch?

Note that I am trying to avoid checking out the entire repository on a temp directory just for that purpose :)

Comment: You would need to specifiy a [difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) that can compare these. It would need to consume the env variables MERGED, LOCAL, REMOTE and create a diff from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a specific version of a file with `git  show`

```
git show origin/main:my_yaml_file
```

After that you need to parse the yaml file to get the diff

For example using `yq`

```
git show origin/main:my_yaml_file|yq eval ".data.version"
```

Will give out the value of data.version

Comment: Just found out about `git show` as well.
Works perfectly! thank you very much!

Comment: For those curious, `git cat-file -p` could also get the same result..... as is usual in git, there is more than one way to do the same task. (upvoted the answer).

Comment: Another thing I have found out is that you need to add `-` at the end of yq command in order to get the input from the pipe if you use a version that is less than 4.18 as mentioned here: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1